# How to change slug in route laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am facing one issue in Laravel, React. So I have NavBar.js file where I am calling some of the routes `category` and `cart` as you can see from below code

```
class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      category: [], cart: [], show: false, showInfo: false, showCat: false, subtotal: 0,
    };
    this.toggleDrawer = this.toggleDrawer.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('category')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ category: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // console.log(error);
      });
  }
toggleDrawer() {
    this.setState({ show: true });

    axios.get('cart')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          cart: Object.values(response.data.content),
          counter: response.data.counter,
        });
      });   
  }
```

These routes are defined in `web.php` file as follow

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
Route::view('/display-item', 'welcome');
Route::view('/checkout', 'welcome');
Route::view('/orderPlaced', 'welcome');
Route::view('/product/{id}', 'welcome');
Route::view('/category/{id}', 'welcome');

Route::get('category', 'CartController@returnCategory');
Route:: get ('cart','CartController@getCart');
```

NavBar file is included in all pages at the top. Everything works good when I am on homepage. URI is called `Request URL: http://localhost:8000/category` and everything is good.

The problem is when I am on page with slug e.g.  `http://localhost:8000/product/2` then URI is called `http://localhost:8000/product/category` which doesn't exist and I have problem.

So my question is: is it possible to manually define slug which will be called from specific page, so if I am on page  `http://localhost:8000/product/2` I want to call `http://localhost:8000/category` instead of `http://localhost:8000/product/category`

I appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Laravel config is fine, the issue lies in how relative URLs work.

When on `http://localhost:8000/product/2`:

- `axios.get('category')` will request `http://localhost:8000/product/category` (relative to the current page)
- `axios.get('/category')` will request `http://localhost:8000/category` (absolute)

Comment: yes.. that's what I have been looking, but I didn't that is called absolute and relative path...thank you so much